# Google Apps Script | Switch Case selecting default option only

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, case

I have a good form, where a user submits data. For learning, I have only one form field, which is a radio button with 2 options.  The resulting spreadsheet has only 2 cols, "Timestamp" and "names."

The goal of my script is to evaluate the event-driven data from the form submission, and then change the value in a variable so emails can be sent to different users. The case never evaluates, and the result is always default.  Here is my script which of which is from other sources: [Digital Inspiration](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/).

> function Initialize() {
>       var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();
>        for(var i in triggers) {
>       ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);   }
>        ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")   .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
>   .onFormSubmit()   .create();    }   function SendGoogleForm(e)  {
>   try    {
>
> ```
> var subject = "Form Test";  
>
> var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
> var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
> var message = "";    
>
> // Credit to Henrique Abreu for fixing the sort order
>
> for(var i in headers) {
>   message += headers[i] + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 
> }
>
> message += headers[1] + "\n";
> message += e.namedValues[headers[1]]; \\ I left this in to check datavalues in the email
> message += e.namedValues[headers[1]]; \\ I left this in to check datavalues in the email
> message += e.namedValues[headers[1]] + "\n";
>
> var email = e.namedValues[headers[1]].toString; \\ I would ASSUME that this would store \\the spreadhseet data to the variable email,
> ```
>
> but it doesn't seem to do that.
>
> ```
> message += "Sheet URL :: " + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl() + "\n";
>
>      switch (email)
>     {
>         case "basdf":
>             email = "email1@hotmail.com";
>             break;
>         case "dfdsa":
>             email = "email2@hotmail.com";
>             break;
>         default:
>             email = "email3@hotmail.com";
>             break;
>     }
>
>
>
>
> MailApp.sendEmail({
>   to: email,
>   subject: subject,
>   body: message,
>   })
>    } catch (e) {
> Logger.log(e.toString());   }
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this snippet. It checks the header column name with the form submitted value and then assigns the corresponding value to the email variable.

```
var email = "";

for(var i in headers) {
  if (headers[i] == "email") {
     email = e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString();
  }
  message += headers[i] + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 
}

switch (email)  {
        case "basdf":
            email = "email1@hotmail.com";
            break;
        case "dfdsa":
            email = "email2@hotmail.com";
            break;
        default:
            email = "email3@hotmail.com";
            break;
    }
```